# cannot interact with javafx webviews

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I can't interact with the webview id=weview and id=accidentview anymore, tried to check/uncheck disable checkbox in scenebuilder still doing the same thing, i guess i messed up something with the pane, but i don't know what is going on, below is my xml configuration file, could this be a bug or something ? I've debug my program it looks fine

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPopup?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1395.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gis_map.ZoningController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar layoutY="2.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="1395.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create new project" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open project" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <TreeView fx:id="treeview" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="438.0" prefWidth="184.0" />
      <TabPane layoutX="947.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="623.0" prefWidth="444.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
            <Tab text="Tools">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="559.0" prefWidth="444.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="cluster" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clusterMakers" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="161.0" text="Cluster" />
                        <Button fx:id="btnsolver" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="116.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="Run VPR_Solver" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Traffic Watch">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TitledPane animated="false" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="593.0" prefWidth="444.0" text="Traffic News">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="476.0" prefWidth="449.0">
                                 <children>
                                     <ImageView fx:id="imageview" fitHeight="273.0" fitWidth="291.0" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="267.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                                    <Button fx:id="portLouis" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="344.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showdrawer" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test" layoutX="178.0" layoutY="307.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ifthereisnocamera" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test1" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="369.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ifthereisnocamera" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test2" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="391.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mokaDrawer" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test3" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="416.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#plaineWilhemDrawer" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test4" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="448.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ifthereisnocamera" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test5" layoutX="243.0" layoutY="307.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ifthereisnocamera" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test6" layoutX="114.0" layoutY="416.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ifthereisnocamera" />
                                    <Button fx:id="test7" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="493.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ifthereisnocamera" />
                                    <JFXListView fx:id="listview" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="263.0" prefWidth="392.0" />
                                    <JFXPopup fx:id="popup" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" />
                                 </children></AnchorPane>
                          </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
          <Tab text="Working Team">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="559.0" prefWidth="444.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="32.0" text="Number of workers" />
                        <Label layoutX="290.0" layoutY="93.0" text="Selection" />
                        <TextField layoutX="156.0" layoutY="28.0" />
                        <ListView layoutX="32.0" layoutY="132.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="147.0" />
                        <ListView layoutX="237.0" layoutY="132.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="154.0" />
                        <Button layoutX="189.0" layoutY="194.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="&gt;&gt;" />
                        <Button layoutX="189.0" layoutY="260.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="&lt;&lt;" />
                        <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="398.0" text="Driver" />
                        <ChoiceBox layoutX="138.0" layoutY="394.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="93.0" text="Waste collectors" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Vehicles">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="543.0" prefWidth="444.0">
                     <children>
                        <TitledPane animated="false" prefHeight="490.0" prefWidth="444.0" text="choose vehicle">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="510.0" prefWidth="442.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="173.0" text="Vehicle 1" />
                                    <Label layoutX="40.0" layoutY="400.0" text="Vehicle 2" />
                                    <Label layoutX="327.0" layoutY="173.0" text="Vehicle 3" />
                                    <Label layoutX="351.0" layoutY="400.0" text="Vehicle 4" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                          </content>
                        </TitledPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab text="Accidents News">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="567.0" prefWidth="444.0">
                     <children>
                        <WebView fx:id="accidentView" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="566.0" prefWidth="444.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
      <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="465.0" prefHeight="186.0" prefWidth="184.0" text="Selection Options">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="radius" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openRadius" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="Within Radius" />
                  <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#activateMeasurement" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Near roads" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <JFXDrawer fx:id="drawer" direction="TOP" disable="true" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="623.0" prefWidth="763.0" />
      <WebView fx:id="webview" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="623.0" prefWidth="763.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Maybe there's something else on top of it. It's difficult to tell from that code. Why are you using absolute positioning for everything, instead of using layout panes that manage the layout for you?